# how can we find this antiderivative

Tags: integration

An other student asked me to compute
$$\int \frac{dx}{\cosh(x)+\sqrt{\cosh(2x)}}$$

but i couldn't give him any answer.
I tried the substitution $$t^2=\cosh(2x)$$
but it made it more difficult.

I thank you in advance for any hint.

Comment: $$-\frac{1}{2} \tanh \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \coth \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-i
   F(i x|2)-i E(i x|2)-\sqrt{\cosh (2 x)} \coth (x)$$ where $F$ is the elliptic function.

Comment: To what end do we seek such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing $\int \frac{dx}{\cosh(x)+\sqrt{2\cosh^2(x)-1}}$ is the same as computing
$$ \int \frac{1}{x+\sqrt{2x^2-1}}\cdot\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\color{red}{\int\frac{\sqrt{2x^2-1}}{(x^2-1)^{3/2}}\,dx}-\color{green}{\int\frac{x}{(x^2-1)^{3/2}}\,dx} $$
where the green integral is elementary but the red one is not.
 By applying integration by parts to the red part the problem boils down to computing
$$ \int \frac{2x^2\,dx}{\sqrt{(2x^2-1)(x^2-1)}}=\int\sqrt{\frac{2x^2-1}{x^2-1}}\,dx+\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(2x^2-1)(x^2-1)}} $$
which is a combination of [elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) of the second and first kind.

Comment: Thank you so much. appreciate.